# NumPy dependency not met when installing pandas on Windows 7

Tags: python, pandas

I was installing pandas but it gives the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.9.3 (from versions: 1.10.4,
1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0,
1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1,
1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3,
1.15.4)
No matching distribution found for numpy==1.9.3
```

I already have numpy 1.9.3 installed in my windows7

My OS is Windows 7 sp1. I tried `pip install numpy` first, then tried `pip install numpy==1.9.3`. I am using python 3.4.

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.9.3
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I tried upgrading pip but it shows

```
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

(venv) C:\Users\admin\PycharmProjects\pythonproject>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
DEPRECATION: Python 3.4 support has been deprecated. pip 19.1 will be the last one supporting it. Please upgrade your Python as Python 3.4 won't be maintained after March 2019 (cf PEP
429).
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\admin\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages (19.0.3)
```

Comment: I recommend you to do a fresh installation (updated python version and then install numpy, pandas...). Also you can install anaconda that comes by default with a stable python + numpy/pandas installation.

Comment: will windows 7 support python version 3.7?

Comment: yes of course! https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: ok thanks....i will try by uninstalling python 3.4

Comment: problem solved...Thank you so much

Comment: Great! I'll write my suggestion as an answer then! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely to come from incompatible versions of python / pandas. I suggest you do the following:

- Uninstall python 3.4
- Install last python version 3.7
- Install numpy / pandas